# [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

Tags: xorg, bumblebee

I am new to linux, I'm using an gt 740m

I am getting this error when I use `optirun`

```
[   55.478327] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[   55.478372] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
driver
```

This is how I installed bumblebee :

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-319-updates nvidia-settings-319-updates
```

I modified theses lines as it was recommanded :

```
KernelDriver=nvidia_319_updates

LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates

XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
```

But Bumbleblee is not working. How can I resolve this ?

My `bumblebee conf` : http://pastebin.com/rZjyuq41

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to install virtualgl & virtualgl-libs. It's not in official repository, so you need to add bumblebee-ppa, then you need to switch from `sausy` to `raring` (only for bumblebee-ppa).

Here's the steps:

1. Add bumblebee-ppa:

   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

   sudo apt-get update
2. Then switch to raring, edit the file (not the name, the contents of it) and change there a string `saucy` to `raring`

   `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bumblebee-stable-saucy.list`
3. Then, install virtualgl (with virtualgl-libs)

   `sudo apt-get install virtualgl`

---

Consider to install the ia32 (i386) libs if you need, this is optional, but suggested by virtualgl x64 package.

Also, you might need this fix: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/fix-bumblebee-libturbojpegso-issue-in.html
Check it before you will made any changes.

I had the same problem, then made all this things and it works.